# Using Interop.Access to get controls in just Header section (or Body or Footer)

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Could you advise how to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` in C# to get all controls of just the header section of a specific Access form?

Thank you.

Comment: All forms will have a `Detail` property, and forms will have additional properties like `FormHeader`, `FormFooter`, `PageHeaderSection`, `PageFooterSection`, etc. if those elements exist in the form. Each of those properties will have a `Controls` collection. Have you tried inspecting those collections?

Comment: Hi, I don't see the property Detail, I don't see the FormHeader or PageHeaderSection either. Do I need to cast the form to something? Thanks

Comment: In VBA those elements are exposed as Properties, while in Office.Interop.Access they are members of the Sections collection. I have posted an answer with some sample code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All forms will have a `Detail` Section and forms will have additional Sections like `FormHeader`, `FormFooter`, `PageHeaderSection`, `PageFooterSection`, etc. if those elements exist in the form. Each of those Sections will have a Controls collection. Here is an example:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // this code requires the following COM reference in the project:
    // Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library
    //
    var objAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");

    string formName = "ClientForm";
    objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm(formName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcFormView.acDesign);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Form frm = objAccess.Forms[formName];

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The FormHeader section of form [{0}] contains the following controls:", formName));
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Control ctl in frm.Section["FormHeader"].Controls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    [{0}]", ctl.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("        {0}", ctl.GetType()));
    }
    objAccess.DoCmd.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acForm, formName);
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
    objAccess.Quit();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Console output:

```
The FormHeader section of form [ClientForm] contains the following controls:

    [Auto_Logo0]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ImageClass

    [Auto_Header0]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.LabelClass

Done.
```

Comment: it looks like we have to hardcode the section name frm.Section["FormHeader"]. is it possible to get the list of sections ordered from top to bottom?

Comment: @khoailang Please create a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to keep the two issues separate.

Comment: Have you any ideas of how could I get the "text" of that control? For example, ctl.Name or ctl.Caption or ctl.Text ?

Comment: @TsalGiorgos - Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @GordThompson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925053/get-the-text-of-headers-and-footers-in-access-using-interop-access