# Get the text of Headers and Footers in Access using Interop.Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
using AccessApi = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

  foreach (AccessApi.Control control in ap.Forms[formName].Section[AccessApi.AcSection.acHeader].Controls)
    {
       logger.Info(control.Name);
    }
```

But with these I get the Name (AutoLogo or AutoTitle) of the control. I want to get the text of the Title for example. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the way I could not access `control.Value` and `control.Caption` was because it wasn't a LabelClass property as @Unhandled Exception said. So I did this:

```
foreach (AccessApi.Control control in ap.Forms[formName].Section[AccessApi.AcSection.acHeader].Controls)
{
    Type t = control.GetType();
    if (t.Equals(typeof(AccessApi.LabelClass)))
    {
        AccessApi.Label label = (AccessApi.Label)control;
        logger.Info(label.Caption);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this approach.

All forms will have a Detail Section and forms will have additional Sections like FormHeader, FormFooter, PageHeaderSection, PageFooterSection, etc. if those elements exist in the form. Each of those Sections will have a Controls collection. Here is an example:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The FormHeader section of form [{0}] contains the following controls:", formName));
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Control ctl in frm.Section["FormHeader"].Controls)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    [{0}]", ctl.Name));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("        {0}", ctl.GetType()));
}
objAccess.DoCmd.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acForm, formName);
objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
objAccess.Quit();
```

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the type of control you want to read the text from.

- If it is a textbox then use `control.Value`.
- If it is a label then use `control.Caption`.

Comment: I have a label but when I write `control.Caption`  or `control.Value` I get a compile error that 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Caption' or 'Value'.

Comment: If you just iterate through all controls in this section that its possible that you also target a control not supporting any of these properties. Do you know the names of the controls you want to read the text from? Then try not to loop, but access them by name.

Comment: How about trying this to access the label of a named control: `ap.Forms[formName].Controls["YourControl"].Value` (exchange `YourControl` by the corrent control name)? Does this work? If not, does this `ap.Forms[formName].Controls["YourControl"].Name` ?

Comment: `ap.Forms[formName].Controls["YourControl"].Name` worked and I got the exact same result with `control.Name` that I mention above. The `.Value` again not a member of my library!

Comment: Ok, so this means that the API seems not to know this property. I can just assume, that you would have (if possible) to use something like `AccessApi.Label` instead of `AccessApi.Control` for labels.

Comment: It seems to be `LabelClass`.