# Access Application.SaveAsText Read Hex values

Tags: vb.net, hex, ms-access-2010

I've exported several Access objects to text files using application.saveastext within a VB.net application. I'm using Microsoft.Interop to accomplish this. Ideally I'm looking to then read through the resultant text file(s) including the hexdecimal portions.

I understand how to load from text using those files in Access but I'm inquiring about how to read the hex values within those files separably in a vb.net application. An example hex string within one of the files looks like this.

```
Begin TextBox
                Enabled = NotDefault
                Locked = NotDefault
                TabStop = NotDefault
                OverlapFlags =85
                IMESentenceMode =3
                Left =4770
                Top =30
                Width =1080
                Height =345
                TabIndex =3
                Name ="Qty Available"
                ControlSource ="Qty Available"
                Format ="General Number"
                EventProcPrefix ="Qty_Available"
                ConditionalFormat = Begin
                    0x0100000090000000010000000000000005000000000000001700000001000000 ,
                    0xff000000ffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
                    0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ,
                    0x5b0046006f0072006d005d0021005b00520065006f0072006400650072002000 ,
                    0x4c006500760065006c005d0000000000
                End
                GUID = Begin
                    0x992063bfd02642489a85ffd951279cb6
                End
                ColumnGroup =3
                GroupTable =6
                HorizontalAnchor =1
                IMEMode =0
            End
```

At this point what I've tried doing is using some online decoders to see if I could easily convert them to a string. What I'm getting instead is special characters and unreadable text. I've searched extensively on various topics related to application.saveastext but Microsoft really hasn't even documented that process and I'm not seeing anything extensive on the subject.

Does anyone have experience with this or can point me in a direction?

Comment: Apologies I'm trying be specific in what I'm asking without adding a bunch of irrelevant infirmation. I thought I outlined my problem and I only included the binary block that I am looking to decode. To further answer your comment above the text file includes the control name and it's properties. However, if there's conditional formatting it places it in a block like what I posted.

Comment: k, updated to show the code from the file for that textbox.

Comment: Why not whole form text export? What about the Controls col loop in my answer? And still the your focus on conditional format is not noted.

Comment: The last two lines of the conditional format look like UTF-16-encoded text.

Answer (score 1):

### How to decode these blocks of hex digits?

In a nutshell: Split them into blocks of two characters (`0x5b0046` -> `5b`, `00`, `46`, ...) and then parse them into a byte array. Here is the code we use to do that:

```
''' <summary>
''' Parses binary data formatted as follows:
'''     0x.... ,
'''     0x.... ,
'''     0x..
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function ParseBinaryData(lines As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Byte()
    Dim colBytes As New List(Of Byte)()

    For Each sLine In lines
        sLine = sLine.TrimStart(" "c).TrimEnd({vbCr(0), vbLf(0), ","c, " "c})
        If Not sLine.StartsWith("0x") Then
            Throw New FormatException($"Line does not start with 0x: {sLine}.")
        End If

        For Each sPair In StringTools.SplitOnLength(sLine, 2).Skip(1)
            colBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(sPair, 16))
        Next
    Next

    Return colBytes.ToArray()
End Function
```

And here's the `StringTools.SplitOnLength` helper method used:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function SplitOnLength(s As String, iSegmentLength As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    s = If(s, "")
    If iSegmentLength < 1 Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("iSegmentLength")

    While s <> ""
        Yield Left(s, iSegmentLength)
        s = Mid(s, iSegmentLength + 1)
    End While
End Function
```

### And what do these byte arrays mean?

It depends. This is what we figured out so far:

- PrtDevNames/PrtDevNamesW are the ANSI/Unicode versions of the [DEVNAMES structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-devnames).
- PrtDevMode/PrtDevModeW are the ANSI/Unicode versions of the [DEVMODE structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea).

What about ConditionalFormat and ConditionalFormat14? Unfortunately, they seem to contain some undocumented binary data structure. Three years ago, I [asked about this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f7ce5d7-9a26-475d-977d-8938df703729/decoding-saveastexts-conditionalformat?forum=accessdev) on MSDN's Access for Developers forum, but the Microsoft employee just politely told me to get lost.

We solved this issue by internally banning Access developers from setting conditional formatting in the Access Form designer and forcing them to use VBA code instead (i.e., manually setting the `FormatConditions` property in code). This might or might not be a suitable solution for you, depending on the size of your legacy codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Get control names of MS-Access forms & reports](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/1647#issuecomment-223074810) and [Quick Overview of SaveAsText and LoadFromText](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/thirdoffive/templates-quick-overview-of-saveastext-and-loadfromtext-aka-lets-get-boring-again).

Structure seems to be:

```
Begin {control-class-name}
    {property-name} = {value}
End
CodeBehindForm
{attributes}
{declarations}
{body}
```

[PrtMip property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.prtmip) in Visual Basic sets or returns the device mode information specified for a form or report in the Print dialog box.

Decoding `ConditionalFormat` property seems hard compared to just looping the Forms Controls-Collection and inspecting the [`FormatConditions` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.formatcondition).

May be sth like (c# code stolen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22038797/9439330)):

```cs
var objAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");

    string formName = "ClientForm";
    objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm(formName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcFormView.acDesign);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Form frm = objAccess.Forms[formName];

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The FormHeader section of form [{0}] contains the following controls:", formName));
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Control ctl in frm.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.FormatCondition fc in ctl.FormatConditions)
        {
            //read  FormatCondition properties here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.formatcondition
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    [{0}]", ctl.Name));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("        {0}", ctl.GetType()));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("           {0}", fc.Backcolor));
            ...
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("           {0}", fc.Type));
        }
    }
    objAccess.DoCmd.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acForm, formName);
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
    objAccess.Quit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did come across that on GitHub as well as the article on so. Problem I ran into is converting that bit of vba code to vb.net and only for the snippet rather than a whole file or calling it within Access like it is in that example. The main section I'm trying to decode is the conditional formatting section, updated in my original post. The other hexadecimal or binary blocks I'm not concerned with. Though cracking one should crack the others.

Comment: Cool beans. I'll give that a look a bit later. Appreciate your assistance